# How to print a very small float value in php?

Tags: php, floating-point, format

I have a function that print calculate the loading time of each page:

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
 $time_start = microtime_float();

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
```

but when I echo the $time, I get something like this:

```
5.60283660889E-5
```

But I would like to have a value like 0.000000000000xxxx, how can I convert this? Thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for your "float" function, just do

```
$time_start = microtime(TRUE);
```

which returns the value as float.

To display the decimals, try

```
printf('%.16f', $time);
```

which tells PHP to format a float with 16 decimal places of output.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf('%f', $time);
```

Take a look at [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) function

Comment: Hm.  This actually does some rounding by default. `php -r 'printf("%f\n", 0.00000289352);'` outputs `0.000003`